# Is there a list online of every bracha?

Tags: blessing, internet

Where can I find online a list of every *bracha*? Including natural phenomena, foods, special occasions, etc.

Comment: Are you counting different versions of Shmone Esrei separately?

Comment: There are eight separate _b'rachos_ that end "_Baruch ata Hashem m'kadesh hashabas_" (not counting slight differences by regional custom or time of year). Answer-seekers would do well to find a list that counts all of them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are many lists of most common brakhot on food and other occasions, e.g.,

- [Halachipedia on food](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=List_of_Brachot_on_food) and [more broadly](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot)
- [Chabad on food](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/278538/jewish/Basic-Blessings-on-Food-Guide.htm) and [other occasions](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2269966/jewish/Blessings-for-Various-Occasions.htm)
- [OU on food](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/)

God bless you :->

Comment: Those list every blessing?

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably not, the end of Massekhet Brakhot has many that we don't usually say - but I took the question to mean a reasonably complete list of most brakhot

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that in your answer

Comment: @DoubleAA Re last comment, "cyclical" thinking, perhaps, for now. The question is vague.

Comment: @DanF On the contrary: _especially_ when a question is vague should one who chooses to answer it be extra clear what he is claiming.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a while different sites I found exactly what I was looking for. There is a website called [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com) which has a [Berachot](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot) section. In it there aren't only berachot, but halachot regarding those berachot.

Comment: Or you could have saved 21 minutes and read my answer :->

Comment: I had already started to write it when I had to deal with something on the real world.