Complete list of all known brachot with shem ha'meforash?
Is there a published book (or even a PDF) with a list of all known hazel(-ic) brachot b'shem ha'meforash? I'd like a list of every known bracha begining with "baruch ata hashem elokeinu melech ha'olam...."

What do you mean by hazal brachot? The ones explicitly listed in the gemara as having shem umalchut? The ones listed in the gemara, that we assume have shem umalchut? Brachot only known from Gaonic times? Brachot commonly said? All brachot that have ever been used by various communities around the world throughout time?

Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67894/is-there-a-list-online-of-every-bracha

I mean brachot founded in the corpus of hazal, using shem umalchut.
Why is this complicated.  Is it hazal?  Does it use shem ha'mforash?  Geonim are usually considered the first post hazal-ic,,,, so not Geonim but if you know a groovy bracha b'shem ha'meforash and malchut from a Gaon, go ahead, I'd love to hear it anyway.
Commonly said? No I'm not interested in stuff that people who don't know anything say.
Various communities?  No, in the textual corpus of Hazal, broadly construed if you like, but in the text and using shem ha'meforash.

I have this bracha wheel ,I can't seem to find one online ,but still looking.
It contains:
Type of bracha
Nusach of bracha
Time when bracha is said
Source in the Talmud & Shulchan Aruch
Bracha wheel:

